# How to set maximum number of reducers per node in Hadoop streaming?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-streaming

I have a C++ based MapReduce jobs and I'm using Hadoop streaming.

However the maximum number of reducers per node end up being `7` even if I set them to `18` in the command line configuration as `mapred.tasktracker.reduce.tasks.maximum=18` ;

Is anything else stopping the reducer from emitting more reduce tasks ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After amending the `mapred.tasktracker.reduce.tasks.maximum` property, are you restarting the task trackers in your cluster? You should be able to go to the Job Tracker web ui page and confirm that each task tracker now has 18 reducer slots configured